# .Bat File does not work with double click, only by the CMD (Set Variable inside IF)

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables

Purpose: I want to create a .bat file to rotate my screen when I flip my monitor vertically as I haven't found any way to access the current state of the monitor to work with, I'm trying to use a variable like: everytime I start my computer the variable isTurned=1 (this means the monitor is rotated), I want this .bat file to change the monitor's rotation based on this value. if the monitor is vertical, rotate to horizontal, and if it is horizontal, rotate to vertical.

I'm Working in a batch file and this %isTurned% is an environment variable that starts with 1.
the problem is, when I double click the .bat file, the variable does not change to 0 inside the first IF. But, if I execute the .bat file using the CMD it works. Any Idea about this?
Turn monitor.bat:

```
IF %isTurned% == 1 (
SET isTurned=0
 C:\Users\user\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /SetOrientation 5 0
echo %isTurned%
)ELSE (
SET isTurned=1
 C:\Users\user\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe /SetOrientation 5 90
echo %isTurned%
)
pause
```

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly, you've got an existing CMD environment where `isTurned` is 1 and you're expecting double-clicking that script to turn the value to 0 in the same environment. Is that correct? If so, it's not going to work because every time you run a script by double-clicking it, a separate instance of the command prompt is spun up, so `isturned` got set to 0 in the new one, but the old value persists in the previous one.

Comment: Also, currently this code as posted will return nothing but a syntax error if `%isturned%` is not defined. enclose your matching criteria in double quotes. `IF "%isTurned%" == "1" (`

Comment: @SomethingDark I created an environment variable called isTurned, and I want to dynamically change it. I will edit the post to a better understanding

Comment: @Gerhard Actually, the code works, but only if I execute the .bat file using the CMD

Comment: Yes, it works. What I am saying is that should your variable not exist you will end up with a match like this `IF  == 1 (` which will cause a syntax error. always enclose the matching criteria in double quotes so at least it still compares something even if the variable is empty `IF "" == "1" (` anyway, back to subject. Do you expext  the variable to be changed permanently in the environment, or only in the environment when the script is running?

Comment: Only the `setx` command can permanently change system variables. There is a caveat to that. It is only available to new instances.

Comment: as @Squashman mentioned, you can do `setx` to permanently set the variable which will only be available when a new `cmd` is started, but a workaround, you can `setx` and `set` the variable which will be available directly.

Comment: Your `echo` commands return the wrong/former value due to lack of [delayed variable expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html); place `set isTurned` instead to indicate the true variable value…

Comment: The only way that the code you posted would work is if you ran it twice from the same command prompt _AND_ if that was your entire code and not just a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

To permanently `set` an environment variable you need to use `setx` but as stated by [`@Squashman`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1417694/squashman) in the comments, there is a caveat that it will only show the change when you restart the `cmd` console (open a new one). If it is required that you use the new variable in the current `cmd` prompt's environment, you can hack it by using both `setx` (to permanently set the variable) and `set` to set it in the current environment as well. Also, in order to not have to use `delayedexpansion` or `call` we remove the option of using the variable inside of the code blocks, you only need to `echo %isTurned%` outside the of the `if/else` statement:

```
@echo off
if "%isTurned%" equ "1" (
    set "isTurned=0"
    setx isTurned 0 
    start "" "C:\Users\user\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe" /SetOrientation 5 0
  ) else (
    set "isTurned=1"
    setx isTurned 1
    start "" "C:\Users\user\multimonitortool-x64\MultiMonitorTool.exe" /SetOrientation 5 90
)
echo %isTurned%
pause
```

*NOTE.*

I do not know `MultiMonitorTool.exe` so I am using the correct way of `start`ing it.